# is there any way to check an email id is present in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, forgot-password, password-recovery

The issue currently facing now is that, we have developed an android with firebase support and we have many users and their data. in the password reset page and need to validate whether the email id is present in the firebase or whether is it a new mail id. how to do this.. please help

Comment: What are you using, realtime or cloud firestore?

Comment: Just sign in with a fake password. Wrong credential, email exist else user doesn't exist. ( Sign in success, fake password  = real password . Lucky guy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` for this.

```
List<String> userSignInMethods = await auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
```

It will return an empty list when the email cannot be found.